# ionic - angular google-chart not working in windows app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, windows-mobile

I wanted to build a ionic mobile app for windows along with charts. i can able to build the windows app but charts are not displaying.

I have created the ionic blank template from VS2015 and integrated angularjs google chart from here https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart

If i try to build the app for android and it work like a charm with same code.

Kindly guide to fix this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any error in console ? Can you add the code ?

Comment: it didnt show any error

Comment: Im getting the below error in the output in VS2015. 

\www\js\angular.min.js.map read failed: Could not find file 
www\js\angular.min.js.map

im including angular.min.js in the index.html

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated the highchart and now i'm able to build the ionic app for windows